What change if I use 8309 Linux LUKS partition type instead of classic 8300 Linux?
When I create the luks partitions I ever used the 8300 Linux type (I use this since the 2000!), today I found a new partition id
sgdisk -L|grep -i luks
8309 Linux LUKS

any advantage to use this instead of 8300?

Since sgdisk operates on the GPT partition table, the number 8309 is a non-standard shorthand for the actual partition type UUID. As far a I know, the number scheme is specific to sgdisk and might even vary between different versions of sgdisk.
Since the description is Linux LUKS, using that partition type would suggest that the contents of that partition would be encrypted with LUKS.
If some partitioning tool is aware of the meaning of that particular type UUID, it might stop the tool from wasting time trying to identify the filesystem type within, as the expectation would be that the contents are encrypted.
Most Linux distributions don't care about partition type identifiers at all; the generally recommended way to identify filesystems is by each filesystem's unique UUID, whenever possible. Reading the filesystem UUID requires knowing the filesystem type in advance, or autodetecting it.
The only real advantage would be that it makes the partition table more descriptive, so if the disk is removed and plugged into another system, it might make it a bit more obvious that the LUKS encryption must be unlocked before making use of the data within.
